# How to display external database contents in android and assign it to the local variable

Tags: android

database fields are

**phone_no**       ||         **count** 
999999999          ||           1     
777777777          ||           2

I have created phone_no activity such that if I enter the phone number it should display the count according to that phone_no below

My code is as follows

```
{
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();   
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/phoneno.php");

String pho = input.getText().toString();

List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairsphedit = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(11);

nameValuePairsphedit.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone_no",pho));

try {
httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairsphedit));
Log.d("myapp", "works till here. 2");

 try {
         HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
         Log.d("myapp", "response " + response.getEntity());
         String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
         Log.d("","Response :"+result);
         JSONObject json=new JSONObject(result);

         count1 = json.getString("count");//count1 is local variable

     } 
catch (Exception e) 
{
     e.printStackTrace();
} 
                    }
```

And my phoneno.php file is as follows

```
<?php

$conn= mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
if (!$conn)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

    mysql_select_db('test',$conn);


    $phone_no = mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['phone_no']);

    $sql="SELECT * FROM meh WHERE phone_no='$phone_no'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());
    if (!$result)
    {
        die('There was a problem executing the query');
    }
    else
    {

    $rs=mysql_fetch_array($result);

    $arrInfo = array('phone_no' => $rs['phone_no'] , 'count' => $rs['count']);

    echo json_encode($arrInfo);

    }
?>
```

Comment: And what is the ouput of the log statements?

Comment: i am trying to print count1 value but its showing null

Answer (score 0):

Use the method below. You are trying to read the response.getEntity() directly. You need to get the InputStream from that entity first and then read the server stream content from that InputStream.

```
public static JSONObject read(String url)  {

    InputStream is = null;
    String result = "";
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    // http post
    try {
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phone_no",pho));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // convert response to string
    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //convert the read response to JSONObject
    try {
        System.out.println("Read data from server :" + result+":");
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return jsonObject;
}
```

Comment: thanks for the replay,but the thing is its displaying "Read data From server:" nothing else i called that method as read("url"); is it the correct way or not please suggest, i need to display only count value not anything else

Comment: it is the correct way of using the code snippet. but you have to pass a valid 'phone_no' parameter for the PHP webservice to return a value. if possible check the proper working of your PHP service by some core java samples.

Comment: please see the above **php code** and tell me that is the way to pass the values to android code i need to print only **count** value thats it, please it seems very simple but i am trying it from past few days

Comment: i am not a PHP guy. but looking in to your PHP code, it seems there are conflicts between the phone_no parameter that you pass from android client and that you receive in PHP code. ie, you pass 'phone_no' from android and try to read 'phone' parameter in PHP. one another error i noted is, you read the post parameter to a local variable 'phone' and in sql query you try to pass 'phone_no' variable. this will also cause problem

Comment: so in your PHP code,  **change** $phone = mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['phone']);
    $sql="SELECT * FROM meh WHERE phone_no='$phone_no'";            **to**  $phone = mysql_escape_string($_REQUEST['phone_no']);

    $sql="SELECT * FROM meh WHERE phone_no='$phone'"; i hope this will work

Comment: its not the problem i changed it before only but showing the  same above as i mentioned

Comment: as i mentioned in last comment, please test your PHP service using a plain java client and make sure that it is working fine. i made a test project for you to test. https://www.dropbox.com/s/y5tqvam2cwji2ja/HTTPTest.zip Use the Test.java class to test your PHP service. Change the BASE_URL parameter to point to your service and pass the request string as required. Adding debug statements in PHP code will also help.